# How to do (i.e. derive) multiplication (using *) of a Rational and a new type

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I'm implementing a small program to handle polynomial operations, inspired by one assignment of upenn's [cis194](https://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis194/). The code is below (I omitted some irrelevant code):

```
newtype Poly = Poly [Rational]
    deriving Eq
s :: Poly
s = Poly [1, 0]

instance Num Poly where
    (Poly a) + (Poly b) = ...
    (Poly a) * (Poly b) = ...
    negate (Poly xs) = ...
    fromInteger i = Poly [fromInteger i]

instance Fractional Poly where
    fromRational f = Poly [fromRational f]

instance Show Poly where
    show (Poly a) = ...

pdiv :: Poly -> Poly -> (Poly, Poly)
pdiv (Poly a) (Poly b) = ...

cauer1 :: Poly -> Poly -> String
cauer1 a b =
    let (q, r) = pdiv a b
    in if r == 0 then (show q) else
        (show q) ++ " + 1/(" ++ (cauer1 b r) ++ ")"
```

This code works. For instance I can get the long division of polynomials' result in order to make a Cauer 1 form circuit using the `cauer1` function. (Circuit Analysis)

```
ghci > let a = Poly [1, 23%6, 10%3, 0] -- represents: s^3 + 23/6 s^2 + 10/3 s
ghci > let b = Poly [1, 3, 2]
ghci > cauer1 a b
"s + 1/(6%5 + 1/(25%42s + 1/(49%5 + 1/(1%14s))))"
```

What I want now is to do something like this:

```
ghci > cauer1 (s^3 + 23%6*s^2 + 10%3*s) (s^2 + 3*s + 2)
```

and get the same result.

At first my `Poly` type is defined as `Poly [Double]`, after making `Poly` instance of `Num` and `Fractional` and implementing `fromInteger` and `fromRational`, I can do something like `s * 1`, `s * 2.3`, `3.4 * s^2`, then the powerful typeclass will compute them as `Poly` without any problem. But in this way the result are all fractional numbers and lose precision, that's why I switched to `Poly [Rational]`. But Now I cannot do `3%2 * s`, they simply type mismatch according to ghc:

```
<interactive>:1:9:
Couldn't match expected type ‘Ratio a’ with actual type ‘Poly’
In the second argument of ‘(*)’, namely ‘s’
In the expression: (3 % 2) * s
```

I found that `Rational` is `Ratio Integer` and `Ratio` is an instance of both `Num` and `Fractional`, why would this not work and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can do something like `s * 1`, `s * 2.3`, `3.4 * s^2` ...

Yes, because (citing from the Prelude documentation):

> A floating literal stands for an application of `fromRational` to a value of type `Rational`, so such literals have type `(Fractional a) => a`.

.. which means that you can use such a literal everywhere you can use a `Poly` (being a subclass of `Fractional`)

The same doesn't hold for e.g. `3%2`, which is not a literal, but an expression with type `Integral a => Ratio a`, which only means I can use such an expression everywhere I can use a `Ratio a` (provided `a` is `Integral`). This is far less flexible.

What you need, then, is an operator `%` such that `3%2` will get a type `(Fractional a) => a`, just like the literal `3.14`

This can be done by redefining it as in the following example

```
import qualified Data.Ratio as R

(%) :: Fractional a => Integer -> Integer -> a
x % y = fromRational ((R.%) x y)

-- the rest as in your example
```

Now you can do

```
*YourExample> :t 3%2 * s -- ask ghci whether this makes sense ...
3%2 * s :: Poly          -- yes, it does!
```